# What are the consequences of a body of mass moving at speed of light?

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, speed-of-light

What would happen to someone who could move at the speed of light?

I know that at the speed of light bodies gain mass and decrease in size. But what would happen to a body gaining mass tending to infinity?

**EDIT:** It is a hypothetical question, I know that an object can't move at the speed of light.

Comment: No object which have mass (my mass I mean rest mass) can reach the speed of light. Because as you go faster and faster you need more energy (or force to push you) and to reach the speed of light you need infinite amount of energy (which doesn't exists), so no object which have a mass can reach the speed of light

Comment: @GigiButbaia I know, I edited my answer

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob: the site rules specifically exclude such questions as *not mainstream physics*.

Comment: Hey, what part of "its an hypothetical question" you do not understand? ahaha

Comment: @LucasAbilidebob, it's not that it's a hypothetical question, it's that it's *nonsensical* question.  If, according to theory A, X cannot be true then the hypothesis that X is true necessarily supposes theory A is false.  But, if theory A is false, then what theory would you like to use to find an answer to your question?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Alfred, I've asked this question because I and any friends enter into a discussion of the famous Flash (DC Comics character), and started thinking about what would happen to a body if he could move at the speed of light. I know that's a nonsense question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and can be proved using Einstien's equation:

$E=mc^2$

If a body of mass approaches a mass of infinity:

$E=\infty \ c^2$

This implies that the energy of that body approaches infinity, thus, everything in the universe would have to be a part of this moving mass.

Comment: I say in the question , look at the P.S , its an hypothetical question (IF a body can move at speed of light) I know, it's impossible.

Comment: I edited your comment then wrote this answer, you then edited it again adding that PS statement. I don't see the need in a down vote.